# Window space configuration doesn't work on logs

Tags: 21.10

In short, I can minimize and maximize the window of the log report but I am not able to move it to the side of the window (putting it one side of the screen, splitting it in half).

I can do it on any other window though.

How come it doesn't work on the log window?

Using 40.4.0 GNOME on wayland, v 21.10.